# SQL Server machine learning services r version 3.5

Tags: r, sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/upgrade-r-and-python?view=sql-server-ver15), SQL Server machine learning service's highest R version is 3.3. Does anyone know when one can upgrade to version 3.5 or later?

Or is my only option to switch to sql server 2019?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well cs0815, let's take a look.

According to your post, you tagged this with sql-server-2017, so I'll be basing this on that version.

After reading through your link and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/sql-r-services-windows-install?view=sql-server-2016&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15#verify-installation), I was thinking there might be two options:

- Hack a new version of R into the R-Services module of SQL server.
- Setup an R-Client with version 3.5

However, it looks like R-Client is for [a different use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-client/what-is-microsoft-r-client#machine-learning-server-vs-r-client) case than you might need so we'll focus on an attempt to replace R in R-Services with a higher version directly.

After installing a new instance of 2017 with the following features: 
[image]

R Services natively installs to:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\R_SERVICES"
```

Using WinDiff, I pulled the following comparisons vs CRAN R 3.5.3 and Microsoft Open R 3.5.3 and not surprisingly the Microsoft Open R is much closer.

Full diffs:
[R_Services vs CRAN R](https://gist.github.com/sgoley/bdd369a8975d505149514b4380c20be2)
[R_Services vs MS OPEN R](https://gist.github.com/sgoley/349e8de2ebc03e48c51665aa5c103c85)

Personally, I'm not at the level to understand all the differences in R Core / runtime between R 3.3 (R_Services) and R 3.5.3 so of main interest to me is the library diff.

What exists in R_Services which does not in Open R is what I'm assuming to be the core of what makes R_Services work with SQL Server so that will be where we need to fill in those gaps with our "replacement" R_Services but with v3.5.3.

Libraries which are *completely* missing - not just added docs or some small difference:

- compatibilityapi
- dorsr
- microsoftml
- mrsdeploy
- olapr
- revopemar
- revoscaler
- revotreeview
- sqlrutils

And that information leads to us to the Microsoft MLS Docs "R Packages" resource:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/introducing-r-server-r-package-reference

Which, no, it looks like those packages are not publicly available through MRAN, CRAN, or even directly via devtools from github.

Still, searching brought me onto this possibility: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/install/upgrade-r-and-python?view=sql-server-2017#offline-binding-no-internet-access

Download after signing up with Visual Studio Dev Services:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/install/machine-learning-server-windows-install#download-machine-learning-server-installer

So - binding this version of MLS to our existing instance: 
[image: MLS 9.4.7 installation]

After that installation is fully complete, let's check and see what's available on our server!

So first things first, this being a new instance of SQL Server - Set to enable external scripts:

```
sp_configure 'external scripts enabled', 1;
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
```

And then to bring this soup to nuts:

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'
print(R.Version())
';
```

output below:

```
$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)"

$nickname
[1] "Eggshell Igloo"
```

TLDR: Yes - download the MLS 9.4.7 packages from Visual Studio Dev Services and install on server host.